# Strange display of my nine-patch background

Tags: android, android-widget

I have some trouble with a nine-patch background I created. It displays good in my ADT Graphical Layout editor, but at Runtime, it just fails. (See how it does at the end of my message)

My layout file contains a button like this (I skipped not interesting stuff) :

`<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/btn_signin" android:id="@+id/loginResaBtn" style="@style/ButtonResa"  android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>`

Maybe You will need that too :

Here is the style I added in my styles.xml

```
<style name="ButtonResa" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_resa</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

And my drawable btn_resa.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_gray" />
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_green" />
<item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_green" />
<item 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_blue" />
```

Regards,
Odissey

[Ninepatchfail2 http://data.imagup.com/7/1120396248.png](http://data.imagup.com/7/1120396248.png)

Comment: Could you post the xml you're using?

Comment: Also, what is the nine patch you are using? just the black background?

Comment: It is resolved. That was just bad ninepatching. I was putting my points on the top just to the left side of my button image. And that created a disproportionnated background (on the right side)

Comment: Please choose your post as the answer then. :)